# How does New Relic Tracing Work for Android?

Tags: android, newrelic

I am currently working on integrating the New Relic Mobile SDK into my Android application I am just curious, at a high level, How does the New Relic tracing work?

How are we able to annotate methods with "@Trace" and New Relic will profile the method without the use of an annotation processor?

Comment: Can you include an example of how you are trying to use @Trace?